# How to create a permanent table from joining 2 temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temp tables, `#trial1` and `#trial2`, with values in them. I want to create one permanent table from joining the two existing temp tables. Here are the structures of the tables.

What I have:

```
table: #trial1
columns: [uID],[SVN],[IN]

table: #trial2
columns: [uID],[PLE],[TS]
```

What I want:

```
table: perm_table
columns: [SVN],[IN],[PLE],[TS]
```

So the two temp tables will have to join on `[uID]`. How can I create one permanent table from joining the two temp tables?

Comment: read about `select into` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the select-into syntax:

```
SELECT [SVN], [IN], [PLE], [TS]
INTO   perm_table
FROM   #trial1 t1
JOIN   #trial2 t2 ON t1.[uID] = t2.[uID]
```

Comment: i tried that originally, but it gave me an error with a message 'Invalid object name '#trial1'.'

Answer (score 1):

You seems want `SELECT....INTO` :

```
select tr1.SVN, tr1.[IN], tr1.[PLE], tr2.[TS] into perm_table
from #trial1 tr1 inner join
     #trial2 tr2
     on tr1.uid = tr2.uid;
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but it gave me the same error with a message 'Invalid object name '#trial1'.'

Comment: @SuinYun. . . `#trial1` is a temporary table not a physical table that you need to create or will create on fly whenever it is required.

Comment: @SuinYun. . . Then you should aware about the session.

Comment: can you please explain? aware is not a verb.

Comment: i don't think the problem is my lack of knowledge of temp table. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @SuinYun. . . According to your error message, your temp table session is expired if you have already one temp table. You need re-create it.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem, because i don't get the error message when i use INSERT INTO. my inner join actually works now. so thanks again for trying to help Yogesh.